# How to change sales price from 4 to 2 decimal digits on main page?

Tags: price, sales

I'm completely newbie to Magento so need full explanation/path to change a sales price from 4 to 2 decimal digits on my main page. On the product page it shows correctly, see California-dreaming.com first dress Katharine.

Seems to require some coding somewhere as couldn't just go to System/Manage Currency/Rates and change the 4 decimal digits it shows there. My prices are usually showing with only 2 digits but adding sales price makes the problem on the main page, and only on that page?!?

I have no idea where the coding takes place, so if someone knows the answer please include the steps to get to the system file where I need to  make a change.

I have Magento 1.9.1.0

Thanks

Senna

Answer (score 0):

As I have checked the source code, found that you have fetch the product listing on home page using custom code instead of using magento function.

Try to use magento functions to format the price like below:
`Mage::helper('core')->currency($products->getPrice(), true, false);`

Also you can use the below magento extension that provide complete control on price display:

[ET Currency Manager Magento Extension](https://marketplace.magento.com/etws-et-currencymanager.html)